# Onclick show next divs

Tags: jquery

I have 1000 divs and 20 of them are visible and remaining are hidden.

In the onClick jquery event, I want the next 20 divs to become visible and so on.

Comment: What have you tried? How are you setting the first twenty to be visible in the first place? Help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

Assign sets of 20 to css classes, and have your jQuery method show all in that class.  You can have a global js variable track number of clicks, then if an if statement, show hide the appropriate sections:

```
<script type="text/javascript">var numberOfClicks = 0;</script>
<style>.IncurredDate1 {} .IncurredDate2 ... {}</style>
<div class="incurredRow1">blah</div>
<div class="incurredRow2">blah</div>
//in click event
<script type="text/javascript">
function buttonClick(event){
    switch(numberOfClicks )
    {
        case 1:
        ...
        case 20;  
            $(".incurredRow1").show();
            break;
        case 21:
        ...
        case 40:
            $(".incurredRow2").show();
            break;
        default:
            code to be executed if n is different from case 1 and 2
     }
   }();    
</script>
```

Comment: Thank You very much GrayFox, Please explain how to assign next 20 divs to a css class?

Comment: I've updated my answer.  In a style section, define 50 classes (50*20 = 1000).  in your 1000 divs add the classes logically by groups.

Comment: Also, if your divs are close, wrap those divs in divs to make management easier.  If not, css classes are the way to go.

Comment: Thank you for your precious time , have any purely jquery code for that without CSS.

Comment: JavaScript, CSS and HTML are inseparable.  How are you going to easily identify the divs without CSS?  You need either an ID or a class to denote which divs are manipulated and which are left alone.  It's only a tiny bit of CSS (the class definitions are empty), take heart!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jquery, you can use the `.slice()` method.

http://api.jquery.com/slice/

Something like:

```
$('button').click(function(e){
  var divs = $('.mydivs');
  divs.hide().slice(0, 20).show(); // 0 is the starting index
});
```

You'd just need to figure out the logic to determine what your starting index is.

I don't have a non-jquery solution, maybe someone else could help on that front.

Comment: Thank You Swat Kins! This is helpful

Comment: let me see your code and I can give you a more specific way to write it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest something akin to the following, though I'd strongly recommend making it into a function, or plugin:

```
var perSlice = 20; // how many to show on each 'page'

// hides all but the first 'page' of the matched elements
$('#wrap > div').hide().slice(0, perSlice).show();

$('a').click(
    function(e) {
            // reference to the elements being 'paged'
        var divs = $('#wrap div'),
            // the first of the visible 'paged' elements
            firstVisible = divs.filter(':visible:first'),
            // the index of the first visible 'paged' elements
            firstVisibleIndex = firstVisible.index('#wrap div'),
            lastVisible = divs.filter(':visible:last'),
            lastVisibleIndex = lastVisible.index('#wrap div'),
            // the index of the first of the 'paged' elements
            firstIndex = divs.filter(':first').index('#wrap div'),
            lastIndex = divs.filter(':last').index('#wrap div');

        // if you've clicked the a element with id="prev"
        if (this.id == 'prev') {
            // prevents the default action of the link
            e.preventDefault();
            // if the index of the first visible element is the same as the
            // index of the first element
            if (firstVisibleIndex == firstIndex) {
                // don't do anything, and exit
                return false;
            }
            else {
                // otherwise, hide all the paged elements
                divs.hide();
                // and then take a selection of those paged elements, and show them
                divs.slice((firstVisibleIndex) - perSlice, firstVisibleIndex).show();
            }
        }
        else if (this.id == 'next') {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (lastVisibleIndex == lastIndex) {
                return false;
            }
            else {
                divs.hide();
                divs.slice((lastVisibleIndex + 1), (lastVisibleIndex + 1) + perSlice).show();
            }
        }
    });​
```

JS Fiddle demo.

References:

- [`event.prevendDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/).
- [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).
- [`:first` selector](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/).
- [`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/).
- [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/).
- [`:last` selector](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/).
- [`slice()`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/).
- [`show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/).
- [`:visible` selector](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/).