# How to pass a Java String to a JavaScript function in a JSP page

Tags: java, jsp

I am looking to pass a string from my Java to a javascript showContent function. Both the Java and javascript are contained in a JSP page. The string `strLine` contains XML content I want to display using the showContent function.

My Java

```
        try{    
        //Open the file that is the first command line parameter
            FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(table.get(xmlMatch));                 

            // Get the object of DataInputStream
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            String strLine;

        //Read File Line By Line
            while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   
            {
                out.println (strLine);
            }
```

The Javascript (I have to credit Peter for supplying me with this in another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12784193/css-javascript-to-display-content-of-next-previous-div-on-user-click))

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
function showContent()
{
document.getElementById('showContent').innerHTML = "printed content";
}
</script>
```

I have tried replacing the above "printed content" with `"strLine";` `(strLine);` and `("strLine");`

I also tried set `strLine` as a session attribute using 
`session.setAttribute("strLine", strLine);` and using `"<%=strLine%>";` but the result was null printed to the screen.

Any help with this would be great.

The HTML

```
<a href="#" onclick="showContent()">Next! <%=keywords%> concept </a>
<div id="showContent"></div>
```

Comment: What content are you trying to print to the screen?  It appears that you are eventually assigning a value of null to strLine, by the end of the System.out while loop.

Comment: The value of `strLine` is 1 - 2 paragraphs of XML content. -  `             out.println (strLine);` currently prints this to the page.

Comment: @Deepend To get the value of the session attribute it should be `<%=session.getAttribute("strLine")?>` and not just `<%=strLine%>` (which refers to the original variable).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of printing it with `out.println`, you should put in a variable (a StringBuilder maybe). In order to do that you have to:

Declare the variable at the right scope (maybe at the beginning of the JSP)

```
StringBuilder contentInnerHtml = new StringBuilder();
```

Then append the text of the file to this new variable:

```
while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   
{
    contentInnerHtml.append(strLine);
}
```

Finally, in the javascript part of the code return its value (with `toString()`):

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
function showContent()
{
    document.getElementById('showContent').innerHTML = "<%=contentInnerHtml.toString()%>";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your html is within your try/catch block, `<%=strLine%>` should work fine.  If not, then assigning it as a session attribute would work as well, however, you need to access it from the session as well:

ex:

```
    try{    
    //Open the file that is the first command line parameter
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(table.get(xmlMatch));                 

        // Get the object of DataInputStream
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String strLine;

    //Read File Line By Line
        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   
        {
%>
<div id="xxx"><%= strLine %></div>
<%
            out.println (strLine);
        }
```

But that is incredibly ugly code and difficult to read/debug.

```
    try{    
    //Open the file that is the first command line parameter
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(table.get(xmlMatch));                 

        // Get the object of DataInputStream
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String strLine;

    //Read File Line By Line
        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   
        {
           session.setAttribute("strLine", strLine);  
           out.println (strLine);

        }  
  } // end of try
  catch( ... ){}
%>

<div id="xxx"> <%= session.getAttribute( "strLine" ) %></div>
```

However, the in the second case, you will only be displaying the last line of your file, so I am not entirely sure what you are trying to accomplish.

If you are hoping to display the full text, perhaps you can use:

```
        StringBuffer strLineBuf;

    //Read File Line By Line
        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   
        {
            strLineBuf.append(strLine).append("<br/>");
        }  
        session.setAttribute( "strLine", strLineBuf.toString() );
```

And then after your try/catch finishes, in your html code:

```
  <div id="xxx"><%= session.getAttribute( strLine ) %> </div>
```