# JavaScript (in jsp) receive String from Java

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, requestdispatcher

Good Morning:

I am having several problems trying to receive a String from Java to JSP (Javascript inside).

Java File

```
String var = "Hello World!";
```

JavaScript (inside the JSP):

```
window.onload = function() { 

    loadData();
};    


function loadData() {

    document.getElementById('paragraph').innerHTML = "<%=var%>";

    alert(matr1); } 
}
```

But I received org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Cannot compile the class.

The rest of JSP and JavaScript is correct, I am trying only to fill the select with the text received in Java, I read other topics but nothing works.

Any help?

Thanks.

Comment: You are calling java method from javascript ?

Comment: No he tries to call a java String from JavaScript. In Android this works fine with JavaScript Interfaces.

Comment: how would JS know any thing about this java code ?  If it is a servlet you could put it in a session attribute

Comment: I think the html file can load the String from java but the corresponding js not -> did not see it.

Comment: In other topics in StackOverflow it says that this works, but nothing works.

Comment: I tried this, does not work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12803341/how-to-pass-a-java-string-to-a-javascript-function-in-a-jsp-page

Comment: Does actually your html file load the java String - did you try without js ?

Comment: So far Wombat is right JS need a session attribute or at least a StringBuilder !

Comment: SOLVED, I receive the data from a Mapped and it works. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your full source of the JSP file, that way we can help you further.

Answer (score 0):

The `<%= %>` or the expression tag is used in `jsp` as a replacement for `out.print()` function of java.
You don't need to put double quotes around it to use it in java script, in your case if you have imported the java file into your `jsp` correctly then i think this should work:

```
document.getElementById('paragraph').innerHTML = <%=var%>;
```

#### Or

try using the variable name directly,

```
document.getElementById('paragraph').innerHTML = var;
```